# Unitary equivalence and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

After a search I did find threads with similar topics, but none with exactly what I want to know.

A matrix $A$ is complex and normal [real and symmetric] if and only if it is unitarily [orthogonally] equivalent to a [real] diagonal matrix.

Write $A$ as $A=P^*DP$.  Then are the entries of $D$ the eigenvalues of $A$?

Let's say $A-tI = Q^*D'Q$.  I believe this is still complex and normal [real and symmetric].  Of course we have $\det(A-tI)=\det(Q^*DQ)=\det(Q^*)\det(D')\det(Q)=\det(D')$, and this does the trick if the entries of $D'$ are $A_{ii}-t$, but I guess it's not clear to me that this is the case.

I suspect this is true, because if it is then some nice things that I'm trying to prove follow from it (wishful thinking, I know).  So how do we prove it?

Comment: If $A = P^{\ast} DP$, then $A - tI = P^{\ast} (D - tI) P$ and $\det(A - tI) = \det(D - tI)$. More generally, eigenvalues are preserved by conjugation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **diagonal** entries of $D$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, yes.

Simply note the eigenvectors of $D$ are the standard vectors, with eigenvalues the diagonal entries. And if $\mathbf{v}_i = P^*\mathbf{e}_i$, then
$$A\mathbf{v}_i = AP^*\mathbf{e}_i = (P^*DP)P^*\mathbf{e}_i = P^*D\mathbf{e}_i = P^*d_{ii}\mathbf{e}_i = d_{ii}(P^*\mathbf{e}_i),$$
so $P^*\mathbf{e}_i$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $d_{ii}$ (the $i$th entry in the diagonal of $D$). Sincee $P^*$ invertible, the vectors $P^*\mathbf{e}_i$ are linearly independent, so this shows $A$ and $D$ have the same eigenvalues with the same multiplicities. And of course, the eigenvalues of $D$ are just the diagonal entries of $D$.

(Note: the argument above applies to any relation by conjugation: if $A=M^{-1}BM$, then $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues with the same multiplicities, since if $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvalue of $B$, then $M^{-1}\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.)

Comment: I take it the collection of $\mathbb{v}_i$ is the basis in which $A$ is unitarily equivalent to $D$?  The only thing I'm not clear on is how we know that $\mathbb{v}_i=P^*\mathbb{e}_i$.

Comment: @Alex: I **define** $v_i$ to be $P^*e_i$; then I show that the $v_i$ are eigenvectors of $A$. Yes, they are **a** basis that realizes the unitary equivalence to $D$, because such a basis is given by the columns of $P^*$. But that fact is irrelevant to the computations.

Comment: Sorry, I know that they were defined that way.  Should have worded it better.  What I wanted to know you answered in your second sentence.  I won't go into further questions here since it is a separate topic.  Thanks.

Comment: $(P^*DP)v = zv$ => $D(Pv) = z(Pv)$ so each eigenvalue of A is also an eigenvalue of the diagonal. This makes the multiplicity argument redundant, i think.

Comment: @HappyFace You are just repeating what I said 11 years ago. Whatks the point? There is no "redundancy", either. I am *noting* that one can thus observe the multiplicities are equal. (Also `\implies`,  not `=>`.ASCII art always looks bad in Mathjax.)