# Showing that if there exist isometries $S_1,S_2 \in L(V)$ such that $T_1 = S_1T_2S_2$, then $T_1$ and $T_2$ have the same singular values.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Suppose that $T_1,T_2 \in L(V)$. I would like to show that if there exist isometries $S_1,S_2 \in L(V)$ such that $T_1 = S_1T_2S_2$, then $T_1$ and $T_2$ have the same singular values.

The proof:

Suppose that there exist isometries $S_1,S_2 \in L(V)$ such that $T_1 = S_1T_2S_2$.

We then have:

$T_1^{*}T_1 = S_2^{*}T_2^{*}S_1^{*}S_1T_2S_2 = S_2^{-1}T_2^{*}T_2S_2$.

The solutions I have say that this implies that $T_1^{*}T_1$ and $T_2^{*}T_2$ have the same eigenvalues and that the corresponding spaces of eigenvectors have the same dimensions. Hence, $T_1,T_2$ have the same singular values.

Can someone please explain to me why this is true? It would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you assuming that $V$ is finite-dimensional? What is $T^*$? Is $V$ a Hilbert space?

Comment: I got stuck on the same exact argument and wrote up a stupidly long mechanical proof, but then I found a way shorter proof in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103499/unitary-equivalence-and-eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T_2 = UDV$ with $D$ diagonal, real, positive and $U$, $D$ unitary (= complex isometries). Then $T_1 = S_1UDVS_2$, which is a singular value decomposition with the same values and unitaries $S_1U$ and $VS_2$. No need to look for eigenvalues. Or what's your question?